# Problem reading XML with Nokogiri using xpath with round brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

I am currently having a problem with Nokogiri XML Parsing.

XML Example:

```
<casting>
<CASTPARTICIPANT>
<person>
<PERSON fullname="John" name="Wick" firstname="John Wick">
<pe_functions/>
</PERSON>
</person>
<function>
<FUNCTION function="Productor"/>
</function>
</CASTPARTICIPANT>
<CASTPARTICIPANT>
<person>
<PERSON fullname="John Wade" name="Wade" firstname="John">
</PERSON>
</person>
<function>
<FUNCTION function="Actor / Principal"/>
</function>
</CASTPARTICIPANT>
<CASTPARTICIPANT>
<person>
<PERSON fullname="Benjamin Franklyn" name="Franklyn" firstname="Benjamin">
</PERSON>
</person>
<function>
<FUNCTION function="Realizer"/>
</function>
</CASTPARTICIPANT>
</casting>
```

When doing doc.xpath("//@name[../../../function/FUNCTION/starts-with(@function,'Actor')]")

I am getting the error:
Invalid expression: //@name[../../../function/FUNCTION/starts-with(@function,'Actor')]

The expression is working on http://xpather.com/

When doing doc.xpath("//@name[../../../function/FUNCTION/@function]") it is working, I also tested doc.xpath("//@name[../../../function/FUNCTION/(@function)]") and it works on http://xpather.com/ but showing the same error with Nokogiri "Invalid expression"

Which make me think is a problem with the round brackets.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Alternatives: `//CASTPARTICIPANT[descendant::FUNCTION[starts-with(@function,"Actor")]]/person/PERSON/@name` or `//CASTPARTICIPANT[descendant::FUNCTION[contains(@function,"Actor")]]/person/PERSON/@name` or `//CASTPARTICIPANT[descendant::FUNCTION[starts-with(@function,"Actor")]]/descendant::PERSON/@name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it works on xpather.com

I think the correct expression should be:

```rb
doc.xpath("//@name[../../../function/FUNCTION[starts_with(@function,'Actor')]]")
```

(note: my NOKOGIRI doesn't support `starts_with`, but the error message clearly states that's the problem, I substituted `contains` for testing)

Comment: It's spelt `starts-with`.

Comment: Thanks Michael/Les, this was the correct way to solve the problem, I really appreciate your help. Best regards! (note: I tested with starts-with and it worked)

Comment: Hi Les, just one more question, from where you get this information. is there a documentation talking about this syntax? Thanks again!

Comment: @JoséDanielRodríguezSánchez well the authoritative source is the xpath specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/ but there is of course much help available all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is valid in XPath 2.0 but not in 1.0, so it's a version problem. XPath 1.0 doesn't allow a function call on the rhs of the "/" operator.

You haven't actually said what you are trying to achieve. The XPath 2.0 expression, while valid, returns a sequence of booleans, one for each selected `@name` attribute, which doesn't seem very useful. It's more likely that you want to retrieve the `PERSON` elements that satisfy some condition - but at this point we're trying to guess your requirements.

Comment: I think if you run it in xpather.com, where OP says "it works" you'll see the result he's trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot for your reply, I will consider this in the future, I really appreciate your help. The thing I was trying to achieve is the person function in an array list. The function in the XML is the tag the contains that value